# Upgrading from ubuntu 14 LTS to 16 LTS, kernel panic

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, kernel

That is quite a long story. I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu 14 LTS to 16 LTS. It was upgrading all fine, until the very end of the process it froze and was stuck for quite a long time.. I ended up restarting it (I know, mea culpa). Of course it didn't boot afterwards, so I I tried to help the situation with Live CD. I tried reinstall it (with option "Something else.."), leaving everything as it was, as I wanted to save all my data and settings. It said it's installed now, but it wouldn't boot properly anyway, now claiming kernel panic..  While trying to fix it, I've got this "no space on the disk issue"..

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           392M   11M  381M   3% /run
/dev/sr0        1,5G  1,5G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      1,4G  1,4G     0 100% /rofs
/cow            2,0G  1,8G  119M  94% /
tmpfs           2,0G  408K  2,0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  8,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2,0G  1,5M  2,0G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           392M   64K  392M   1% /run/user/999
```

I'm getting hopeless here. Is there anyone could help me out?

Comment: Before you do anything else, liveboot it and grab your data.

Comment: Well, I have my files backed up the problem is I forgot to back up my firefox bookmarks, other settings etc... And well, that is very important to me. I tried to find the folders with that kind of data through Live CD, I would find it but I wouldn't get the access to it. Not sure how can get around this?